# How to delete all records returned by a subquery?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-delete

I want to delete all records that are returned by a certain query, but I can't figure out a proper way to do this. I tried to `DELETE FROM mytable WHERE EXISTS (subquery)`, however, that deleted all records from the table and not just the ones selected by the subquery.

My subquery looks like this:

```
SELECT 
MAX(columnA) as columnA,
-- 50 other columns
FROM myTable 
GROUP BY
-- the 50 other columns above
having count(*) > 1;
```

This should be easy enough, but my mind is just stuck right now. I'm thankful for any suggestions.

Edit: columnA is not unique (also no other column in that table is globally unique)

Comment: You need a correlated sub-query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Presumably, you want to use `in`:

```
DELETE FROM myTable
    WHERE columnA IN (SELECT MAX(columnA) as columnA
                      FROM myTable 
                      GROUP BY -- the 50 other columns above 
                      HAVING count(*) > 1
                     );
```

This assumes that `columnA` is *globally* unique in the table.  Otherwise, you will have to work a bit harder.

```
DELETE FROM myTable t
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM (SELECT MAX(columnA) as columnA,
                               col1, col2, . . .
                        FROM myTable 
                        GROUP BY -- the 50 other columns above 
                        HAVING count(*) > 1
                       ) t2
                  WHERE t.columnA = t2.columnA AND
                        t.col1 = t2.col1 AND
                        t.col2 = t2.col2 AND . . .
                 );
```

And, even this isn't guaranteed to work if any of the columns have `NULL` values (although the conditions can be easily modified to handle this).

Comment: It's not unique, that's the problem :) Uniqueness is only achieved by aggregating all 50 columns as well as using the MAX() on columnA. The second solution looks interesting though, I'll try it.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution if the uniqueness is only guaranteed by a set of columns:

```
delete table1 where (col1, col2, ...) in (
    select min(col1), col2, ...
    from table1 
    where...
    group by col2, ...
)
```

`Null` values will be ignored and not deleted.

To achieve this, try something like

```
with data (id, val1, val2) as 
(
select 1, '10', 10 from dual union all
select 2, '20', 21 from dual union all
select 2, null, 21 from dual union all
select 2, '20', null from dual 
)
-- map null values in column to a nonexistent value in this column
select * from data d where (d.id, nvl(d.val1, '#<null>')) in 
(select dd.id, nvl(dd.val1, '#<null>') from data dd)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to delete all the rows of a table such that the value of a given field is in the result of a query, you can use something like

```
delete table
my column in ( select column from ...)
```

Comment: That would only work if column was a unique value, unfortunately it isn't in my case. The only way I can get a unique record is by aggregating all 50 columns and using a `MAX()` function on columnA